# Не получается программа

Tags: pascal, алгоритм

Здравствуйте!

Паскаль не знаю, поэтому, возможно, ошибка в синтаксисе. В алгоритме вроде всё верно написал. Помогите довести её до рабочего вида. Срочно надо. :)

Задача:

> В заданный текст произвольной длины (>0) входят только цифры и большие латинские буквы. Определить, удовлетворяет ли он условию: текст содержит (помимо букв) только одну цифру, причём её числовое значение равно длине текста.

Третья версия кода(рабочая): (Почему не работает в констуркции case закоментированый косок код, т.е. присвоение K:= k+1;)

```
program D_6_41_M(input, output);

var
  i, b, k: integer;
  s: char;

begin
  i := 0; b := 0; k := 0;
  read(s);
  while(ord (s) <> ord('.')) do
  begin
    if ((ord(s) >= ord('A')) and (ord(s) <= ord('Z'))) then begin b := b + 1; end
    else begin
      case s of
        '1': i := 1; //k:= k+1;
        '2': i := 2; //k:= k+1;
        '3': i := 3; //k:= k+1;
        '4': i := 4; //k:= k+1; 
        '5': i := 5; //k:= k+1;
        '6': i := 6; //k:= k+1;
        '7': i := 7; //k:= k+1;
        '8': i := 8; //k:= k+1;
        '9': i := 9; //k:= k+1; 
        '0': i := 0; //k:= k+1;
      end;
    end;
    read(s);
  end;

  if (b = i) then
    writeln('Uslovie vypolneno')
  else
    writeln('Uslovie NE vypolneno');

 end.
```

Спасибо.

Comment: А текст ошибки?

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev, "6.41-HW-Pas.pas(11) : Встречено 'else', а ожидался оператор". Компилирую в PascalABC.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК уберите точку с запятой перед else

Comment: @DreamChild, не знал, убрал, спасибо. Немного подредактировал, но теперь зацикливается. Что исправить?

Comment: @ВладиславМСК может, вам стоит все же приложить хотя бы какие-то усилия для того, чтобы выполнить задачу?

Comment: @DreamChild, представленный Вам код мой. Я уже нагуглил, почему не нужно было ставить точку с запятой и примного Вам за это благодарен. Сейчас реально не знаю, почему программа не работает. Допустим, при вводе: "ABCD4." она просто перестаёт вводить данные и ничего не выводит, при этом не завершается. Просто трудность, что я Паскаль изучаю на ходу(

Comment: @ВладиславМСК запустил ваш код - он работает. Уж не знаю, правильно ли, не проверял. Однако никаких зависаний и зацикливаний

Comment: @DreamChild, он у маня тоже запускается. Вы пробовали вводить данные?

Comment: @ВладиславМСК разумеется

Comment: @ВладиславМСК ответьте себе на 2 вопроса:
Какого типа ваша переменная `s`?
Что делает функция `readln(s)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вместо Readln нужно использовать Read, чтобы читать ввод посимвольно, а не построчно.
2. По задаче правильное условие для цикла -- Eof, а не сравнение на точку.
3. Логика заполнения b и i вообще странная. Во-первых, если встречен недопустимый символ, то из программы можно сразу выйти. Во-вторых, в b разумно хранить количество цифр, поэтому увеличивать её нужно каждую итерацию, а не только в частном случае. В-третьих, непонятно зачем суммирование в i.

Answer (score 1):

После end перед else не должно быть точки с запятой.

Comment: Если исходная строка не содержит точки, то и будет зацикливаться. Надо еще проверять длину строки.

Comment: @Алексей Шаповалов, @Дож, @DreamChild, Спасибо, разобрался в ошибке и написал новый код. Подскажите, почему закомментированная конструкция //k:= k+1; не работает?

Comment: Потому что это комментарий. Все, что в нем содержится, игнорируется компилятором.

Comment: @Алексей Шаповалов, да вы просто гений!! Я надеюсь, это был Ваш сарказм. Я закоментил, чтоюы показать, что код работает. Если убрать, то он ругается на "6.41-HW-Pas.pas(16) : Встречено ':=', а ожидалось ';'" Почему так происходит?

Comment: @ВладиславМСК простите, а в каком учебном заведении вы обучаетесь?